# How to add a number to int when in loop in Python

Tags: python

So i am new to programming in general and i am trying to make a number guessing system so it would give you 7 tries and how many tries you had at the end when the number was guessed

tried already doing this

```
    if c < z:
        print('Higher')
        print('Tries ' + str(count) + '/7')
        count += 1
        this()
```

but it didn't work. Some advice would be much appreciated.

Code:

```
count = 1
z = random.randint(1, 100)


def this():


    inpt = input('Enter a Number: ')
    c = int(inpt)

    if c >= 101:
        print('Number too high only 1-100')
        this()

    if c <= 0:
        print('Number too low only 1-100')
        this()

    if c > z:
        print('Lower')
        print('Tries ' + str(count) + '/7')
        this()

    if c < z:
        print('Higher')
        print('Tries ' + str(count) + '/7')
        this()

    if c == z:
        print('Success! You guessed the number')
        quit(0)


this()

if count == 7:
    print('You lose!')
    quit(1)
```

Comment: there is no loop in your second code.

Comment: After defining your function, add a while loop. "while count < 7". Indent the rest four spaces, add count = count  + 1 to the c<>z, and it'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to do it calling the same method name over again and literally just need a loop to go a certain number of times you can do something like this:

```
count = 0
guesses_allowed = 7
number_to_guess = 5

while (count < 7):
    guess = input("Guess a number:")

    if guess >= 101:
        print('Number too high only 1-100')
    elif guess <= 0:
        print('Number too low only 1-100')
    elif guess > number_to_guess:
        print('Lower')
        count += 1
        print('Tries ' + str(count) + '/7')
    elif guess < number_to_guess:
        print('Higher')
        count += 1
        print('Tries ' + str(count) + '/7')

    if count >= guesses_allowed:
        print('You guessed too many times')
        quit(0)

    if guess == number_to_guess:
        print('Success! You guessed the number')
        quit(0)
```

And then modify as needed for changing the `number_to_guess` or the `guesses_allowed` variable.  Haven't ran this code locally yet as I just typed it out but it should get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make count and z global variables so that they can be used in this(). Then make (If c < z) and (If c > z) increase count by 1. Count needs to start at 0.

Then, when the number is guessed, you need to print the number of tries by printing the concatenation of ('It took you ' + count (number of tries) + ' tries to guess the number!'). You need to concatenate the string value of count because count is an integer and integers cannot be concatenated with strings.

Code:

```
global count #MAKE count GLOBAL
count = 0
global z #MAKE z GLOBAL
z = random.randint(1, 100)


def this():

    inpt = input('Enter a Number: ')
    c = int(inpt)

    if c >= 101:
        print('Number too high only 1-100')
        this()

    if c <= 0:
        print('Number too low only 1-100')
        this()

    if c > z:
        print('Lower')
        print('Tries ' + str(count) + '/7')
        count += 1 #INCREASE count BY 1
        this()

    if c < z:
        print('Higher')
        print('Tries ' + str(count) + '/7')
        count += 1 #INCREASE count BY 1
        this()

    if c == z:
        print('Success! You guessed the number')
        print('It took you ' + str(count) + ' tries to guess the number!')
        #print 'It took you X tries to guess the number!' where X is the number of tries it took them to guess the number  
        quit(0)

this()

if count == 7:
    print('You lose!')
    quit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you should be calling the function in a loop. That would be the better style here. You just need to handle the case for inputs > 100 and < 1

```
import random 

count = 1
z = random.randint(1, 100)


def this():

    inpt = input('Enter a Number: ')
    c = int(inpt)

    if c >= 101:
        print('Number too high only 1-100')

    if c <= 0:
        print('Number too low only 1-100')

    if c > z:
        print('Lower')
        print('Tries ' + str(count) + '/7')

    if c < z:
        print('Higher')
        print('Tries ' + str(count) + '/7')

    if c == z:
        print('Success! You guessed the number')
        quit(0)



while count <= 7:
    this()
    count = count+1

print('You lose!')
quit(1)
```